# Power to many numbers

Tags: python

I have a program that must calculate power to many number like this:

Entry:

```
3
2 3 6
```

So, the program must calculate:

```
2**(3**6)
```

I've written a program that can calculate only the power of 3 numbers. But, if I try to calculate the power of 4 or more numbers, the program will output an incorrect value:

```
nb = int(input())
numbers = list(map(int,input().split()))
lenth = len(numbers)-2
rez = 0
n = 1
for i in range(lenth):
    rez += numbers[n]**numbers[n+1]
    n+=1
tot = numbers[0] ** rez
print(tot)
```

Comment: Why are you adding to `rez`? There's nothing in the problem statement about addition, just calculating powers.

Comment: Are you sure it should be `2 ** (3 ** 6)` and not `(2 ** 3) ** 6`?

Answer (score 6):

You can use `functools.reduce` and the builtin function `pow` (if you are using python 2, `reduce` is a builtin, too)

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> reduce(pow, [2, 3, 6])
262144
```

*Edit:*

As pointed out in the comments, this would actually calculate `((((a**b)**c)**d)**e)`. To get the result of `a**(b**(c**(d**e))))`, you can still use reduce, but you would have to reverse the input arguments list and create a flipped `pow` function: `lambda a, b: b**a`

```
>>> reduce(lambda a, b: b**a, reversed([2, 3, 6]))
```

As a function:

```
def super_pow(*args):
    return reduce(lambda a, b: b**a, reversed(args))
```

Note that this can easily produce enormous numbers that can't be calculated or fit in system memory, leading to your computer freezing.

Comment: @Taher This is much better than my solution.  Good to know!

Comment: This will calculate `(2 ** 3) ** 6` rather than `2 ** (3 ** 6)`

Comment: @Barmar: Thanks for pointing that out. I've updated the answer.